# DatePickerDialog called by a spinner onClick

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, spinner, android-spinner

I cant find anything on sof or google! so i need your help!
id like to click on my (empty) spinner, so i get a date or timepicker dialog shown. I cant find anything how to handle that. these are my snippets for now.:

just my 2 objects:

```
DatePickerDialog dDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, (OnDateSetListener) this, 2012, 3, 3);


        Spinner dSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

xml:

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:prompt="@string/hint_date"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

maybe you have an idea how to handle that. I want to pick a date, call the picker, by onClick(what's not possible with spinners?!) I tried onclicklisteners as well.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: i know this link very much.. but not possible with spinners :| i tried!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why do you even have an empty `Spinner`?  So you just want your `Spinner` to function like a `Button` that shows a `DatePickerDialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spinnerMode` attribute is not what you're looking for. In order to show that `DatePickerDialog` when the user clicks the `Spinner` you'll have to create a custom `Spinner` widget and override the `performClick` method which is responsible for showing the default dialog with the `Spinner`'s values. Below is an example:

```
public class CustomSpinnerDialog extends Spinner {

        // implement all the constructors   

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        DatePickerDialog dDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                new OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }, 2012, 3, 3);
        dDialog.show();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then all you have to do is use this custom `Spinner` in your layout.

Comment: hmm i dont get it... how do I use it in my Activity? I created an Object CustomSpinner, set up the LayoutParametrs, how can i get it shown??

Comment: @user1707493 You'll just use it like you would use a normal `Spinner`. For example, in your question you have a `Spinner` declared in the xml layout. You would use the custom Spinner like this:`<com.your.package.CustomSpinnerDialog
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:prompt="@string/hint_date"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

Answer (score 2):

Better way to do this is by masking a button to Spinner style as done in the Stock Contacts Application Edit Contact screen.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_view"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
        android:paddingStart="12dip" />
```